# How to use regex within powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, sharepoint, powershell-3.0

I need to iterate through all site collections and through all subsites, and print out only the subsites with a certain pattern:

```
/sites/clientcode/oppcode6digits
```

Each client site collection has many subsites, but I only need the ones which URL is at the end 6-digit code.

I have this so far but not working:

```
$SPWebApp = Get-SPWebApplication "https://mylocalurl.com"

foreach ($SPSite in $SPWebApp.Sites) {
    if ($SPSite -ne $null -and $SPSite.Url -notmatch "billing" -and $SPSite.Url -notmatch "administrativedocuments" -and $SPSite.Url -notmatch "documentation" -and $SPSite.Url -notmatch "help" -and $SPSite.Url -notmatch "marketing" -and $SPSite.Url -and $SPSite.Url -notmatch "search" -and $SPSite.Url -ne $rootDMS  ) {
        foreach ($web in $SPSite.AllWebs) {
            $regex = ‘\b[0-9]{6}\b’  
            $patrn = "https://mylocalurl/sites/*/$regex"

            Write-Host $web.Url | select-string -Pattern $patrn
        }
    }
    $SPSite.Dispose()
}
```

Comment: Try `"https://mylocalurl/sites/.*/\d{6}\`$"`

Comment: still doesnt work

Comment: Well, the pattern matches `https://mylocalurl/sites/abc/123456`, so I believe there is a problem not related to regex. Maybe there are 6 digits right after `sites`? Then try `"https://mylocalurl/sites/(?:[^/]*/)*\d{6}$"`

Comment: this is the result, it should match the ones with the arrow https://www.screencast.com/t/FqDnNuG2m3nm

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/oIYWDO/1, the pattern I shared last seems to do what you want.

Comment: yes, so I guess the issue is in the powershell syntax, will check it out

Comment: BTW the `-notmatch` operator is also RegEx based and instead of all the -and and -notmatch combine that with the RegEx or `|`  to: `if ($SPSite -ne $null -and $SPSite.Url -notmatch "billing|administrativedocuments|documentation|help|marketing|search" -and $SPSite.Url  -ne $rootDMS  )`

Comment: nice! thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the regex I suggested together with your code fix:

```
foreach ($web in $SPSite.AllWebs) {
    $patrn ='^https://mylocalurl/sites/(?:[^/]*/)*\d{6}$'
    if( $web.Url –match  $patrn) {
        Write-Host $web.Url
    }
}
```

The regex is

```
^https://mylocalurl/sites/(?:[^/]*/)*\d{6}$
```

See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/oIYWDO/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of line
- `https://mylocalurl/sites/` - a literal substring
- `(?:[^/]*/)*` - 0+ occurrences of 0+ chars other than `/` (`[^/]*`) followed with `/`
- `\d{6}` - 6 digits
- `$` - end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the last line to:

```
  if( $web.Url –match  $patrn)
                {
                    Write-Host $web.Url
                }
```